# Constraint Algorithm Optimization in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I'm especially interested in ways to further optimize a constraint algorithm. So far I've switched to SIMD sse4 vector operations which nearly doubled the performance. I'm hoping there is more performance to squeeze out that I simply don't see.

Here is the algorithm:

```
FVector4 rest(REST_DISTANCE); // Set the constant simd vector outside the loop
FVector4 stiffness(STIFFNESS);

for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
{
    const auto& constraint = Constraints[i];
    auto& position1 = Particle[constraint.first].Position;
    auto& position2 = Particle[constraint.second].Position;

    for (int j = 0; j < ITERATION_COUNT; j++)
    {
        auto delta = position2 - position1;
        auto distance = delta.norm();

        auto correctionDistance = (distance - rest) / distance;
        auto pCorrection = correctionDistance * delta * stiffness;

        position1 += pCorrection;
        position2 -= pCorrection;
    }
}
```

`Constraints` is an array of a simple struct that holds two unsigned int's, `Particle` is an array of `FParticle` structs which holds three `FVector4` fields and a `Fvector4` simply wraps a `__m128` and provides operators and functions like `norm()` which utilize `_mm_*` intrinsic functions.

Currently the algorithm takes 55 cycles per Constraint per Iteration, this is with `TEST_SIZE` of 150,000 and `ITERATION_COUNT` at 16. I know there is performance to gain from making it parallel but I'm hoping to get more performance out of the single threaded version specifically.

I can post the actual structs if needed.

FVector4 code:

```
struct FVector4
{
    FVector4()
    {}
    explicit FVector4(const __m128& InitData) : Data(InitData)
    {
    }
    explicit FVector4(__m128&& InitData) : Data(InitData)
    {
    }
    explicit FVector4(float InitValue)
    {
        Data = _mm_set_ps1(InitValue);
    }
    explicit FVector4(float X, float Y, float Z, float W = 0.f)
    {
        Data = _mm_setr_ps(X, Y, Z, W);
    }

    __forceinline float& operator[](int index)
    {
        return Data.m128_f32[index];
    }
    __forceinline const float& operator[](int index) const
    {
        return Data.m128_f32[index];
    }
    __forceinline __m128 squaredNorm() const
    {
        return _mm_dp_ps(Data, Data, 0x7F);
    }
    __forceinline __m128 norm() const
    {
        auto sqNorm = squaredNorm();
        return _mm_mul_ps(sqNorm, _mm_rsqrt_ps(sqNorm));
    }
    __forceinline __m128 normalized() const
    {
        auto dp = _mm_dp_ps(Data, Data, 0x7F);
        dp = _mm_rsqrt_ps(dp);
        return _mm_mul_ps(Data, dp);
    }
    __forceinline void normalize()
    {
        Data = normalized();
    }
    __m128 Data;
};
```

Operators as used in the algorithm:

```
__forceinline FVector4 operator-(const FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    return FVector4(_mm_sub_ps(a.Data, b.Data));
}
__forceinline FVector4 operator*(const FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    return FVector4(_mm_mul_ps(a.Data, b.Data));
}
__forceinline FVector4 operator/(const FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    return FVector4(_mm_mul_ps(a.Data, _mm_rcp_ps(b.Data)));
}
__forceinline FVector4& operator+=(FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    a.Data = _mm_add_ps(a.Data, b.Data);
    return a;
}
__forceinline FVector4& operator-=(FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    a.Data = _mm_sub_ps(a.Data, b.Data);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about SSE and can't offer you any suggestions on performance right now, just a few suggestions to improve your code a little bit. Nevertheless, it looks well written and clean.

- Since the default constructor does nothing, you can make it `= default`. That's the new syntax for such cases since C++11. It also conveys more meaning that you want a default no-op constructor.
- The move constructor is pointless. An `__m128` is a native type like an integer, so it fits in a CPU register. It will always be copied. You can remove this constructor overload.
- The other constructor that takes a `__m128` by const reference is probably less efficient that it could be. Again, `__m128` can be passed via registers, so taking by reference will instead pass a pointer that has to be dereferenced. I bet you it is generating more code than if you'd just pass it by value.
- The constructor that takes the four X,Y,Z,W floats doesn't have to be `explicit`. For any constructor taking more than one argument that has no default, `explicit` doesn't make sense. It is only meaningful when the constructor has a single required argument and you want to force writing something like `func(FVector{42.0f})`. If the constructor takes more than one argument, it can't be implicitly called.
- `const float& operator[](int index) const` should instead return by value. Again you are forcing the compiler to generate indirection code when the value can be cheaply passed in a register.
- I would also recommend `assert`ing in the array subscript operators to ensure `index` in `>= 0 && < 4`.
- If you decide to port this code in the future, `__forceinline` is going to be a problem. It is a Microsoft extension. I would `#define` a portable macro for it instead or just use standard `inline`. `__forceinline` is no guarantee of inlining, despite the misleading name. It just provides a slightly stronger hint to the compiler than `inline`.
- `__m128` is somewhat an ugly type to pass around, with those double underscores. In your place, I would declare some alias for it, perhaps `simd_t` or something. It might even be of value in the future if you decide to port `FVector` to some other SIMD set like [AltiVec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltiVec).

Answer (score 1):

```
    auto delta = position2 - position1;
    auto distance = delta.norm();

    auto correctionDistance = (distance - rest) / distance;
    auto pCorrection = correctionDistance * delta * stiffness;
```

I would mark these all as `const auto` as they aren't changing during each loop cycle and might enable the compiler to make certain optimizations it couldn't do before as well as express their `const`ness to the reader.

EDIT: If you're willing to make certain assumptions about `ITERATION_COUNT`, you might be able to do a little manual loop unrolling.

Comment: True, I'll make those changes and try it. Yes, the iteration count will never go below 4 so I could unroll it at least that many times.